# Поиск по вложенным массивам в javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, search

Здравствуйте. Ломаю голову над задачей по поиску в массиве содержащем неизвестное количество вложенных массивов. Функция должна просто показывать есть ли такой элемент или нет, принимает два аргумента: собственно массив и искомый элемент. Но по ходу зашел в тупик. Буду благодарен любым подсказкам по данному вопросу. Спасибо.

```
function deepSearch (array, item) {
      var len = array.length;
         for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        if(array[i] == Array){
          if(array[i].deepSearch(array, item)){
        return true;
        break;
      }
        else {
        if(array[i]==item){
          return true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

пример применения:

```
console.log(deepSearch([1, 2, [3, 7, [22, [23]], 4, 5], 17], 7));
```

Comment: `if(array[i] == Array){`? возможно тут имелось ввиду `array[i] instanceof Array`

Comment: вместо `if(array[i] == Array)` наверное надо `if( Array.isArray( array[i]))` или, если не поддерживается, `if( Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]')` – [источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: Пробовал эти два метода - выдает ошибку **array[i].deepSearch is not a function** в строке 'if(array[i].deepSearch(array, item)){'

Comment: @K.Miro, потому что у элемента массива нет функции `deepSpeech`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов с использованием функции [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
function deepSearch(array, item) {
  return array.some(function s(el) {
    return el == item || ((el instanceof Array) && el.some(s));
  })
}

document.write("array: [1, 2, [3, 7, [22, [23]], 4, 5], 17], item: 22, search: " + deepSearch([1, 2, [3, 7, [22, [23]], 4, 5], 17], 22));
```

Стоит быть внимательнее к форматированию кода. Помимо двух ошибок с определением массив элемент или нет и вызов функции для элемента, есть так же проблема со скобками вокруг if.

```js
function deepSearch(array, item) {
  console.log(array, item);
  var len = array.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (array[i] instanceof Array) { // array[i] == Array
      if (deepSearch(array[i], item)) { // было array[i].deepSearch(array, item)
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      if (array[i] == item) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

document.write("array: [1, 2, [3, 7, [22, [23]], 4, 5], 17], item: 7, search: " + deepSearch([1, 2, [3, 7, [22, [23]], 4, 5], 17], 7));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ошибок** несколько:

1. неправильно определяете, массив ли попался. У современного JS есть метод [`Array.isArray(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), проверяющий, массив ли его аргумент.
2. если вы уже возвращаете из ф-ии результат, то после `return` ничего не выполнится – `break` не нужен.
3. `deepSearch()` в вашем коде никак не может оказаться методом объекта `array[i]` – поэтому так вызывать нельзя: `array[i].deepSearch()`

**Алгоритм** ведь довольно простой:

1. На вход получаем массив и рассматриваем его как одномерный, перебираем элементы по очереди.
2. Если элемент равен искомому – всё, выход с `true`.
3. Если попался массив – то вызываем эту же ф-ю и передаём элемент-массив туда параметром. Если этот вызов возвращает `true`, то же самое, как если просто нашли искомое в элементе. Всё.

```js
function deepSearch(arr, item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i]) && deepSearch(arr[i], item)) {
      return true;
    } else if (arr[i] === item) {
      return true;
    } else {
      // ищем дальше
    }
  }
  return false;
}

document.body.innerHTML += deepSearch([1, 2, [3, 7, [22, [23]], 4, 5], 17], 7).toString() + ' ';
document.body.innerHTML += deepSearch([1, 2, [3, 7, [22, [23]], 4, 5], 17], 9).toString();
```

**Сократить** код можно до нечитаемых двух строк:

```
function deepSearch(arr, item) {
    for ( var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) if( arr[i]===item || (Array.isArray(arr[i])  &&  deepSearch(arr[i], item))) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Если код должен быть внутри списка - нужно добавить еще один уровень отступа в 4 пробела, если вынести из списка, то я нашел только способ отбитие текстом

Comment: я оформил в итоге сниппетом )

Comment: Зато теперь знаешь вариант с блоком :)

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо Вам большое за детальное объяснение. Теперь стало понятно в чем у меня ошибки. Вариант с использованием some конечно вообще прекрасен. Надо мне учить дальше.

Comment: @Sergiks Вам так же большое спасибо! Хотел бы я научится писать столь изящные решения в две строчки кода.